# Добавления данных связаных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Как сформировать добавления заказа в БД при такой структуре используя PHP. Создания нового заказа (добавления в `orders`) делаю `INSERT INTO`orders`(dt, pm) VALUES ($dt, $pm)`, а вот как зполнять связанную таблицу, не могу понять.

```
 CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `material` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`)
);

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id_order` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pm` VARCHAR(9) NULL DEFAULT '-',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`)
)
CREATE TABLE `orders_products` (
    `id_order` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`, `id_product`),
INDEX `id_product` (`id_product`),
CONSTRAINT `id_order` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id_order`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `id_product` FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `products` (`id_product`)
)
```

**UPD**
Вроде бы сделал, все добавляет

```
public function newOrder($id_product, $data)
{
    try {
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $dt  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        $this->db->exec("INSERT INTO `orders` (dt, pm) VALUES ('$dt', '{$data['pm']}')");
        $last_id =  $this->db->lastInsertId();
        $this->db->exec("INSERT INTO `orders_products` (id_order, id_product, quantity, price, equipment)
                VALUES ($last_id, $id_product, {$data['quantity']}, {$data['price']}, {$data['id_equipment']})");
        $this->db->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->db->rollBack();
        echo "Ошибка: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

А если нужно к примеру добавить товар в БД, и одновременно добавить в заказ его.То есть товар может быть в БД, и нет. Сделать еще транзакцию для данного случая ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это все надо оформлять как транзакции. Т.е. начинаете транзакцию, вставляете исходные и связанные записи, комитите. Если во время выполнения update`а была ошибка, значит делаете rollback.

Текущий вставленный id в `orders` можно получить через [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

И раз транзакции, значит должна быть InnoDB.